# In parseServer, does `user.save()` supposed to create a session object in database?

Tags: parse-server

I'm creating a new user (server side, nodejs) using `new (Parse.Object.extend("_User"))` then set username, password, and call `.save()` on it. I see that a new session is being created in the database.

I do expect that behavior for `signUp` but does `save` suppose to do that?

Comment: Side Note: You should not be extending the object like that for a User object.  `new Parse.User()` should suffice.  As a little extra, you also don't have to do a `Parse.Query('_User')`, you should do `Parse.Query(Parse.User)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the signUp method on the user objects in order to signUp the user with parse-server like mentioned in [here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#signing-up)

After signing up parse-server will return a session token in the response, so you can store it and use it the next time the user is returning back to your app. The same is relevant for [logging in a user](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#logging-in) back with your service.